# Is this an Intellij Idea bug?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, inner-classes

I downloaded the community edition, the version is 13.1.2.

My following snippet got `Variable 'name' might not have been initialized` error when I used name to initialize innerName. However, it could be run.

```
public class Foo {
    private final String name;

    class Inner {
        private String innerName = "inner" + name;
    }

    public Foo(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't say it's a bug (possibly a case of IntelliJ being overzealous, though I don't think that's a bad thing). Technically you could attempt to create an instance of `Inner` in your constructor before assigning `name`. I'd recommend you to not do it this way and just pass the `name` to the constructor.

Comment: That's an interesting point... Did a quick test, seems that if you create an `Inner` instance in the constructor, `name` is `null`. Not sure if this is intended or not... Could be that IntelliJ realizes that this is unexpected behavior and emits an error that isn't technically required (as you pointed out)

Answer (score 1):

I think that this *might* be a bug. `javac` 1.8.0_05 and Eclipse 4.4M7 do not complain.

In addition, regular nested classes must have an enclosing instance, so that means you cannot have an instance of `Inner` without an instance of `Foo` already existing, which means `name` must have been initialized.

While I could be wrong, there isn't anything immediately obvious that I can see that would indicate that the code as is is incorrect.

Edit: @Cubic brought up an interesting point. Now I'm not very sure what the correct behavior would be.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is, because class is successfully compiled by `javac` and it should be compilable as `name` is initialized within every constructor of `Foo`. You should file a bug to [JetBrains' YouTrack](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com)

Comment: `javac` isn't infallible. I'd use a more substantive explanation.

Comment: @user3580294 it is, but in this case everything should be right, because `name` is initalized within every constructor.

Comment: So then put something like that as your explanation instead of "`javac` compiles it, so it must be right"